# Prove that this is a legitimate PMF

Tags: random

[image]

I know that these are two properties of PMF.

Non-negativity

Sum over the support equals  1

However I can't show that this PMF's sum over the support equals 1.

Comment: @gammatester wow, i didn't even think about Taylor series! Now it is too obvious. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Taylor series for $e^{\lambda}$ you have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_X(k) =
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda} \frac{{\lambda}^k}{k!}
= e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{{\lambda}^k}{k!}
= e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda} = 1 $$